# Stopping creation of .localized files

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystems, finder, localization

Some folders on my new Mac has `.localized` files in them.

I know they are related to localization (duh), but I don't need that, in fact I specifically want everything file system related to be displayed in English (even though I'm Swedish).

I am also aware that I can "hide" them with default settings in Finder. But I want to see other "hidden" files. Also, I often use the command line, and I don't want to be distracted by these files when I do `ls -a`.

So, I don't want these files to exist at all (not just hide them).

Is some process generating these files? If so can I stop that from happening? Can I just find and remove all of the `.localized` files?

Examples of folders I've found `.localized` files in: `~/Music`, `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Applications`, `/Applications`, `/System`

They always appear to be empty, having length zero.

This is on a Mac mini 2020 with an M1 Apple silicon processor and macOS Big Sur.

EDIT: Clarification: I am not talking about files with the *extension* `.localized`, I am talking about files with *just* the name `.localized` and nothing more.

Comment: I haven't noticed files named `.localized`, but I've seen folders with a `.localized` suffix/extension, like `~/Music/Media.localized`.  I'd also like to know if this can be turned off for folder suffixes.

Comment: Not a full solution, but in a terminal you can use GNU ls with the following flag `--ignore=".DS_Store|.localized"`